# Getting Value Of a Particular Row On Clicking On the LinkButton Inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview As Follows :

```
<asp:GridView ID="PartnerView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                       AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridViewStyle" 
                       GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="Partnerid" Width="900px"> 
  <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Partnername" HeaderText="Partner Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="partnertype" HeaderText="Type"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"/> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email ID" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Show_Button" Text="Show" runat="server" OnClick="Show_Button_click"></asp:LinkButton>                                          
                                      </ItemTemplate>    
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns> 
            </asp:GridView>
```

And i have the LinkBUtton inside the gridview....Now i want that when i click on the LinkBUtton inside the gridview i want to get the data only of that particular row.....in the next page..

Comment: What does "in the next page" mean?

Comment: Means when clicked on the show button the details of that particular row will be displayed on the other page....like other tab u can say

Comment: Next page is not an error for me.......That i have coded but i m stuck up in row data bound event

Answer (score 1):

You get the GridViewRow via the LinkButton's NamingContainer:

```
protected void Show_Button_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton Show_Button = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)Show_Button.NamingContainer;
    // now you can get all other fields via FindControl(in case it's a TemplateField)
    //  or via row.Cells[index].Text
    // Then Response.Redirect to the other page and pass appropriate URL-Parameters
}
```

Comment: IS it possible by something like RowDataBound Event ?

Comment: @NimishKulkarni: A LinkButton always posts back to the current page. So you might want to use a Hyperlink instead. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=147